# How to implement google signin hybrid server-side flow without python oauth2client lib

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, oauth2client

I have implemented hybrid server side google signin flow using python27. Where webapp sends one time code to backend and backend replaces with refresh_token, id_token and access_token. I have followed this doc to implement this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

But looks like oauth2client is deprecated. And according to deprecated notes google-auth does not have any method to implement one time code auth flow.

Code below is handling one time auth_code and replaces with tokens. What is the best way to do this for both python 2.7 and 3.7 without oauth2client?

```
from apiclient import discovery
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = '/path/to/client_secret.json'

# Exchange auth code for access token, refresh token, and ID token
credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
                   CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
                   ['profile', 'email'],
                   auth_code)
```

Comment: Use Google auth library

Comment: @tehhowch google-auth does not have method exposed for onetime code flow

Comment: If you do not want to use a library, you can just make an HTTP POST to the Google endpoint. This article shows how to do this using the CLI `curl`. Very easy to do: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to achieve your script without `oauth2client`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, I used `google_auth_oauthlib`. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Create the flow using the client secrets file from the Google API Console.
flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'],
    redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')

# Tell the user to go to the authorization URL.
auth_url, _ = flow.authorization_url(prompt='consent')

print('Please go to this URL: {}'.format(auth_url))

# The user will get an authorization code. This code is used to get the access token.
code = input('Enter the authorization code: ')
flow.fetch_token(code=code)
credentials = flow.credentials

# Retrieve file list using Drive API. This is a sample.
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
files = service.files().list(pageSize=5).execute()
print(files)
```

- In this sample script, when this script is run, the URL for retrieving the authorization code is displayed to the console. When you got the code and put it to the console, when Drive API is enabled, the file list can be retrieved.

#### Reference:

- [google_auth_oauthlib.flow module](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: your solution solves the issue. Just little modification. Authorisation is done by front end. And code is passed to backend. Redirect_uri is also not available at backend. I am trying to find out if this can be done without redirect_uri.

Comment: @Abhilasha Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the method without `redirect_uri`, I have no solution now. I apologize for this situation. For example, `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` is automatically created when the credential is created, so I usually use this. How about this? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps?hl=en#step-1-send-a-request-to-googles-oauth-20-server

Comment: For now I am using only webapp so getting redirect url from web is not an issue. I will look into this further.

Comment: Tanaike looks like google-auth-oauthlib is experimental integration. Is it good to use this ?
https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @Abhilasha Thank you for replying. When I saw [the current QUickstart of Python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) which was updated recently, google-auth-oauthlib is used. oauth2client had been used before. So I'm using google-auth-oauthlib.   If that is changed, I would like to also do it. If this was not the answer you want, I apologize.